# Topological sort for DAG as reverse of DFS

Tags: algorithm, graph, python-3.8, topological-sort

**As we know, reverse of output of DFS is Topological sort.**

Source:- http://www.cse.ust.hk/faculty/golin/COMP271Sp03/Notes/MyL08.pdf

so I tried this and wrote a function for topological sort which is given below:-

```
class Solution:
    
    #Function to return list containing vertices in Topological order.
    def dfs(self, v, adj):
        # Code here
        self.visited.add(v)
        self.stack.append(v)
        for i in adj[v]:
            if i not in self.visited:
                self.dfs(i,adj)
                
    def topoSort(self, V, adj):
        # Code here
        self.visited=set()
        self.stack=[]
        for i in range(V):
            if i not in self.visited:
                self.dfs(i,adj)
        return self.stack[::-1]


#{ 
#  Driver Code Starts
# Driver Program


        

if __name__=='__main__':
    t = int(input())
    for i in range(t):
        e,N = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
        adj = [[] for i in range(N)]
        
        for i in range(e):
            u,v=map(int,input().split())
            adj[u].append(v)
            
        ob = Solution()
        
        res = ob.topoSort(N, adj)
        
        print(res)
```

Can someone tell me please about the correctness of the topoSort function in the given code?

Comment: move `self.stack.append` *after* the children

Comment: @MattTimmermans but in the case of dfs , that is the right position

Comment: so, why should i move self.stack.append after the children

Comment: There is no "correct" output from a DFS.  In a topological sort, the parent needs to come before its children (by definition).  In a reversed topological sort, then, it has to come after.  The source you quote says to output at "finish time".  You have output at "start time".

Comment: You should add the current node to stack once all of its adjacent nodes are visited. So, as @MattTimmermans said, you have to move self.stack.append after the for loop